# problemas con los meta para compartir en facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-api

Estoy creando mi página web, pero ahora con la nueva api me pide compartir mis publicaciones con un link y mediante eso facebook consigue las imágenes, títulos, subtítulos para generar la publicación para compartir (ya que la api anterior uno ponía los parámetros manualmente y era PERFECTO!!)

el problema que ingreso los dichosos "meta" después del "head" pero al hacer la prueba...
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/
me sale:

```
Could Not Connect To Server
Check that the webserver is running, and that there are no firewalls blocking Facebook's crawlers.
```

y según yo, tengo bien los datos de la página de ejemplo es en: 
http://perritosperdidos.org/noticias/labrador-salva-venado

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es-MX" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta content="yes" name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable"/>
  <meta name="viewport" id="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
  <title>PerritosPerdidos.ORG</title>
  <meta property="fb:app_id" content="1592837927687015" /> 
  <meta property="og:type" content="article" /> 
  <meta property="og:url" content="http://perritosperdidos.org/noticias/labrador-salva-venado" /> 
  <meta property="og:title" content="Perro labrador salva a un venado de morir ahogado (Video)" />
  <meta property="og:image" content="http://perritosperdidos.org/noticias/1500326913098.jpg" />
  <meta property="og:description" content="El ciervo se está recuperando de algunas garrapatas y una lesión ocular." />
<script type="application/ld+json">{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "BreadcrumbList",
    "itemListElement": [{
        "@type": "ListItem",
        "position": 1,
        "item": {
            "@type": "WebSite",
            "@id": "http://perritosperdidos.org/",
            "name": "Inicio"                                               
        }
    },{
        "@type": "ListItem",
        "position": 2,
        "item": {
            "@type": "WebPage",
            "@id": "http://perritosperdidos.org/noticias/",
            "name": "Noticias"
        }
    },{
        "@type": "ListItem",
        "position": 3,
        "item": {
            "@type": "WebPage",
            "@id": "http://perritosperdidos.org/noticias/labrador-salva-venado/",
            "name": "Perro labrador salva a un venado de morir ahogado (Video)"                                
        }
    }    ]
}
</script>
</head>
```

Llamo a mi hosting y después de varias pruebas me dicen "todo está bien" y me dicen que el problema es de facebook, entonces ya no se que hacer...

¿alguien que este teniendo problemas o haya tenido algo parecido?

Answer (score 0):

El problema tiene pinta de ser de facebook, porque con [otro debugger](http://iframely.com/debug?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fperritosperdidos.org%2Fnoticias%2Flabrador-salva-venado) de Open Graph funciona bien.

Comment: si gracias por la respuesta, había probado con otro debugger y también me mostró sin problemas. escribí igual mi problema en los foros de desarrollador en facebook por si es un bug y si igual me pueden ayudar.